# Why doesn't Stream.mapToInt handle NullPointerExceptions?

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, java-stream

This code will give NullPointerException. Isn't the mapToInt (map) method supposed to handle NPE?

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(null, null);
OptionalDouble op = list.stream()
    .mapToInt(val->val)
    .average();
```

Comment: No. Why do you think so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you expect it to handle `NullPointerException`?

The lambda expression `val->val` is equivalent to:

```
new ToIntFunction<Integer> () {
    int applyAsInt(Integer value) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And when a method that has an `int` return type returns an `Integer`, auto-unboxing takes place. This means `value.intValue()` is called, and if `value` is `null`, `NullPointerException` is thrown.

`mapToInt()` simply calls the `applyAsInt()` method of the `ToIntFunction` instance passed to it for each element of the `Stream`.

It has no reason to check that an element is `null` and somehow handle it, since it has no way of knowing how you wish to deal with `null`s. It's the job of the `ToIntFunction` instance to decide that, and your `ToIntFunction` doesn't handle `null`s.

Comment: What's the point of returning OptionalDouble if it still throws NPE? Then it should return simple double, not OptionalDouble

Comment: @Alexander the point is that if the IntStream is empty,  average() would return an empty OptionalDouble.

Answer (score 3):

As Eran has already noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62811480/10584605), the `mapToInt` is not supposed to handle NPE.

You have to deal with it instead, by providing your custom null-check logic. E.g.:

```
OptionalDouble op = list.stream()
                        .mapToInt(val -> val == null ? 0 : val)
                        .average();
```

Comment: why not `filter` them?

Comment: @Naman Well, then the `average()` won't reflect the number of input values. Ultimately it's up to OP to decide whether he needs the nulls or not.

Comment: @Naman `average` of `(null, null, 3)` is either `1` or `3`, depending on whether you consider nulls as `0` or filter them out.

Comment: surely it wouldn't and it should be up to the OP,  also then what would you expect the output for `Arrays.asList(null, null);` as in question to be? can consider leaving an edit in the answer for the varied behaviors.

Comment: @Naman `Arrays.asList(null, null);` has obviously been added as an example here. I've just mentioned one way of dealing with nulls. One can filter them out if needed, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly new to Java but had a similar problem. Reading over this and the documentation I came up with this -keep in mind, I'm using it for a slightly different reason but you will see how I was able to filter out the possibility of nulls to avoid the NPE.

```
positions.stream().filter(i -> i != null).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```